# Showing a side navigation in ReactJS with pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have:

```
function ShowNav(props) {
    const isLoggedIn = props.isAuthenticated;
    if(isLoggedIn) {
        return 'Show nav';
    } else {
        return 'Hide nav';
    }
}
render() {
        return (

            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <ShowNav isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}/>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                    <Route path="/companies" component={CompanyList}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
```

But it appears that my  component overrides the other pages so their content doesn't get displayed. How do I make it so that the navbar will show on those pages together with their content?

Comment: Move `ShowNav` outside the `Router`.

Comment: Make it an answer and I'll accept, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ShowNav(props) {
    const isLoggedIn = props.isAuthenticated;
    if(isLoggedIn) {
        return 'Show nav';
    } else {
        return 'Hide nav';
    }
}
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ShowNav isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}/>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                        <Route path="/companies" component={CompanyList}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Moving the ShowNav outside the router will make sure that it is always displayed irrespective of the routes.